# Numpy mean returning 0 on a large set of data - works fine on small set of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, bigdata

I've been writing a script that gets min, max, mean etc from a large data set in Python (cannot share code due to it being work-related).

I've noticed that running np.mean on a pandas dataframe (`600 columns x 10 rows`) it returns a mean value correctly.

However, when running it on a large scale dataset (`600 columns x 20000 rows`) it is always returning `0.0` as the `min`, `max` and `mean` of the dataset.

Am i missing something obvious with NumPy that is common?

Thanks :)

Expecting min, max and mean results, not receiving any by using np.mean etc.

Comment: try `df.describe`. it will show you statistics about your data. You may have zero-mean data.

Comment: can you give us an example of how you use `np.mean()` for your calculations? I cannot replicate your error

Comment: @coder00 That wouldn't explain why the min and max are also zero though. The only way that's possible is if every one of those millions of numbers is precisely zero, which even a cursory look at the data would rule out.

Comment: What if you create a DF by: ```a = np.zeros((20000, 600), dtype="float64")```, ```a[::2] = 1.0```, ```df = pd.DataFrame(a)```. Does this produce the expected min, max and mean?

Comment: `df1.apply(lambda col: np.nanmean(df1[col.name] - df2[col.name])).replace(0, np.nan).abs()` is the example for mean diff between two dataframes with identical columns. Like i say, each row is populated, and this code works on a dataset which is much smaller

Comment: @fdireito your example works fine, i have a suspicion it is to do with null values in the source data - will look into handling NULLs before reaching averaging stage

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - as suspected it was due to NULL/NaN values in the source data:

So i changed:
`df1.apply(lambda col: np.nanmean(df1[col.name] - df2[col.name])).replace(0, np.nan).abs()`

to

`df1.apply(lambda col: np.nanmean(df1[col.name].replace(np.nan, 0) - df2[col.name].replace(np.nan, 0))).replace(0, np.nan).abs()`